# Wix checking netfreamwork 4 during installation of files

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I experienced strange behavior from wix. I created installation and when I wanted to test it, everything works fine, my dialog shows... But when I clicked on install, it looks like it is installing but in one third of installation files message box pop up saying: Installation of MYPRODUCT requires .NET Framework 4!

My first idea was that I have bad launch condition... but still it is launch condition and not install or what... so I deleted it a problem still is there...

Then I thought that it is maybe because of my custom action in C#, so I deleted it also, but problem is still there. Any idea?
Thanks

and btw. that launch conditions (netframework) are working fine...

**EDIT: if I set InstallScope="perUser" it works...**

Log:

```
Action start 12:54:33: INSTALL.
MSI (s) (A0:F4) [12:54:33:505]: Running ExecuteSequence
MSI (s) (A0:F4) [12:54:33:505]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
Action 12:54:33: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 12:54:33: FindRelatedProducts.
MSI (s) (A0:F4) [12:54:33:507]: Skipping FindRelatedProducts action: not run in maintenance mode
Action ended 12:54:33: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 0.
MSI (s) (A0:F4) [12:54:33:507]: Doing action: AppSearch
Action 12:54:33: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
Action start 12:54:33: AppSearch.
AppSearch: Property: FM70HOME, Signature: FM70_HOME_PathRegistry
MSI (s) (A0:F4) [12:54:33:508]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (A0:F4) [12:54:33:508]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE32\SOFTWARE\Adobe\FrameMaker\7.0 3: 2 
AppSearch: Property: FM71HOME, Signature: FM71_HOME_PathRegistry
MSI (s) (A0:F4) [12:54:33:509]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (A0:F4) [12:54:33:509]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding FM71HOME property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\FrameMaker7.1'.
AppSearch: Property: FM72HOME, Signature: FM72_HOME_PathRegistry
MSI (s) (A0:F4) [12:54:33:509]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (A0:F4) [12:54:33:509]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE32\SOFTWARE\Adobe\FrameMaker\7.2 3: 2 
AppSearch: Property: FM80HOME, Signature: FM80_HOME_PathRegistry
MSI (s) (A0:F4) [12:54:33:510]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (A0:F4) [12:54:33:510]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding FM80HOME property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\FrameMaker8\'.
AppSearch: Property: FM10HOME, Signature: FM10_HOME_PathRegistry
MSI (s) (A0:F4) [12:54:33:510]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (A0:F4) [12:54:33:510]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding FM10HOME property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\AdobeFrameMaker10\'.
AppSearch: Property: NETFRAMEWORK45, Signature: NetFramework45
MSI (s) (A0:F4) [12:54:33:510]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
Action ended 12:54:33: AppSearch. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (A0:F4) [12:54:33:511]: Doing action: LaunchConditions
Action 12:54:33: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
Action start 12:54:33: LaunchConditions.
Installation of eAIP.wiz@rd requires .NET Framework 4!
MSI (s) (A0:F4) [12:54:40:586]: Product: Product -- Installation of Product requires .NET Framework 4!

Action ended 12:54:40: LaunchConditions. Return value 3.
Action ended 12:54:40: INSTALL. Return value 3.
```

also I have no idea why it check for NetFramework45... 
My launch conditions are:

```
<Condition Message="Installation of Product requires .NET Framework 40 full!">NETFRAMEWORK40FULL OR REMOVE ~= "ALL"</Condition>
        <Condition Message="Installation of Product requires Framework!">NOT WF_INSTALLED = "NOT INSTALLED" OR REMOVE ~= "ALL"</Condition>
        <Condition Message="Can't find any of Adobe Framemaker 10.0, 8.0, 7.2, 7.1, 7.0 installation.! Product would not be working.">FM10HOME OR FM80HOME OR FM72HOME OR FM71HOME OR REMOVE ~= "ALL"</Condition>
```

**And why it writes message that requries .Net Framework 4, when firt time launch condition passed... and when I have net framework 4 full installed?**

**Full log:** http://pastebin.com/eEGCnQXu

Comment: Are any of your files to be installed in a .NET GAC? Perhaps you should have a launch condition that checks for .NET Framework 4?

Comment: well as I told you, I had launch condition for NETFX4FULL check and it pass without any problem, but during the installations popups another check and I do not understand from where...

Comment: Hmm I just notice that it popups that message about net framework when it installs and status above progress bar is Evaluating launch conditions... So what is wrong? it can mean that launch condition is not checked because otherwise it would fail on start?

Comment: The log file you posted indicates that the installation is stopped by the launch condition. Probably, there's another log snippet you're talking about?

Comment: I posted whole log from installation, but the installation stopped on that launch condition... I mean progress bar was half green and then the launch conditions were triggered? Like wtf?

Comment: Also what is strange, that launch condition which is triggered during installation is not in my install file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok probably I found a solution.

The whole problem is logged in my log:

```
MSI (c) (B8:58) [12:54:23:788]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
Action 12:54:23: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 12:54:23: FindRelatedProducts.
FindRelatedProducts: Found application: xxx
MSI (c) (B8:58) [12:54:23:788]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED property. Its value is 'xxx'.
MSI (c) (B8:58) [12:54:23:788]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MIGRATE property. Its value is 'xxx'.
FindRelatedProducts: Found application: xxx
```

which telling that I have already installed that product... at least some registry must be there... so I changed product guid and upgrade.. and it works... but it is still strange to me, why it tells that net framework 4 is missing when it passed at launch condition at beginning.